# SSD or HDD for Kafka Brokers? ( Using SSD for Kafka )

Tags: apache-kafka

Kafka is fast because it uses sequential writing techniques on HDD.

If I use SSD for Kafka Brokers, do I get faster performance?

As far as I know, SSD works differently than HDD. And I think with SSD I wouldn't get sequential writes privileges. I'm worried that using SSD wouldn't be good for Kafka brokers.

**My questions :**

1. Is SSD better than HDD for Kafka Brokers?
2. Does the "sequential write technique" also apply to SSD?

Comment: 1 No, for sequential access is better HDD
2 No, SSD provide easier random access. Though keep an eye on the evolving technology, as there may be some optimizations (of which I'm not aware of at the moment)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SSD are best for Zookeeper servers, not the brokers.

> If I use SSD for Kafka Brokers, do I get faster performance?

Honestly, that is up for you to benchmark for your use-cases

However, Kafka does sequential scans/writes, not random flash access of data (what SSDs are meant for), therefore spinning disks are preferred , regardless of claimed speeds of SSD

https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/deployment.html#disks

Also, disk pools (JBOD) and partition schemas are important, and [ZFS seems to get good gains](https://kafka-summit.org/sessions/kafka-zfs-better-living-filesystems/) over XFS or ext4

Answer (score 4):

I have run Kafka in production for 8 years with 1mio messages per second.

Spinning disks will only work as long as you can avoid lagging consumers. If you have too many, disk access will look like random I/O and spinning disk-based Kafka clusters will fail (tested for you).

Do not put Kafka on consumer drives, we tried, they die hard after about 1 year. Enterprise NVMe is awesome, if you can afford it. Currently experimenting with a 22 disk ssd raid0. 10gbit+ nics is a must.